# Greasemonkey script in Firefox 4, want to change one line of code on webpage

Tags: html, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

Alright, I will try to make this is as simple as possible, without being too vague.  I want to change one of line of code on a webpage in hopes of preventing a preview pane from appearing.

Original line of code

```
<div id="previewpane" class="previewpane" sytle="height: 139px;">
```

I want to replace the above line with

```
<div id="previewpane" class="previewpane previewpane-hide" style="height:139px;">
```

I have previously written one Greasemonkey [script](http://ipatch.penguinmilitia.net/greasemonkey-scripts/) but unfortunately I am have having difficulty applying the techniques learned from that script into this new one, thus this post.

cheers
-Chris

Comment: You could probably use [Stylish](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/) to achieve the same effect. I think the CSS would be `#previewpane { display: none !important; }` assuming that the previewpane-hide class does what I assume it does...

Comment: @MatrixFrog:  You're right. Stylish would be better for accomplishing the OP's stated page-change.  I suspect there may be more going on, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty easy.  Here's a complete script that should work (change the include line).

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Easy Page tweaker
// @description     Hides pane?
// @include         http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @require         http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

$("#previewpane").addClass ("previewpane-hide");
```